# Grails: JS function to change src of img is not responding

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, grails

I am trying to change the src of an img under a certain condition. I know the condition returns true appropriately, because I previously wrote in an alert(). For some reason, the function is not changing the src of the img and dynamically updating the page. Could this have anything to do with the fact that I am using the jquery library? I would think you can still use the stand js syntax. Here are my code snippets and the corresponding source code from google chrome.

.gsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSuccess(data){
    if(data.hasHearted){
        document.getElementById("changer${user.id}").src = "${resource(dir: "images/images", file: "heart_red.png")}";
    }       
}
```

```
<figcaption id="secondcap" onClick="${remoteFunction(controller:'user', action:'heart', onSuccess: 'onSuccess(data)', params:[userID:user.id])}">               
            <img id="changer${user.id}" src="${resource(dir: "images/images", file: "heart.png")}" alt="heart">
</figcaption>
```

Chrome source (I've omitted some things for privacy):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSuccess(data){
    if(data.hasHearted){
        $('#changer3').attr('src','/Personably/static/images/images/heart_red.png');
    }       
}
</script>

<div class="persons">   
<figure class="user_image">         
    <img class="user_profile_pic" src="omitted for privacy..." onmouseover="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'userID': '3'}, url:'/Personably/user/hasHearted',success:function(data,textStatus){onSuccess(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});"/>  
    <figcaption id="firstcap">
            Omitted for privacy...
    </figcaption>               
    <figcaption id="secondcap" onClick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'userID': '3'}, url:'/Personably/user/heart',success:function(data,textStatus){onSuccess(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});">                
            <img id="changer3" src="/Personably/static/images/images/heart.png" alt="heart">
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jquery, have you tried using the jquery id selector $(“#id”) and/or the jquery .attr function?

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that changing the src attribute after the page is loaded will change what the user sees, even if it changes the code, because the document is already loaded.

Instead, you should probably put both images (heart.png and heart_red.png) on the page, and then hide/unhide them with styles depending on the output of your controller action. The jquery .toggle(Boolean) method can be very useful for stuff like this. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Inside your JavaScript function, you could just have something like:

```
$('#heart3').toggle(!data.hearted);
$('#heart_red3').toggle(data.hearted);
```

Then, when data.hearted is true, red heart will show, and plain heart will hide.